# Generate abstract syntax tree for Java source code?

Tags: java, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

For my project, I need to:

1. Convert Java source code into an AST.
2. Modify the AST (e.g. add statements, modify expressions).
3. Convert the AST back into source code for compilation.

I know that ANTLR can parse Java code, but it looks like I would have to tweak the grammar file to produce an AST. Is there an out-of-the-box solution that will get me an AST?

Comment: Would [this](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser) work?

Comment: [Graal and Truffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graal_%28compiler%29) are two compiler projects of oracle. Especially if you want to compile again.

Comment: JavaCC will do this out of the box.

Comment: @EJP:  I don't think JavaCC will "convert AST back to source".

Comment: @IraBaxter Purchasing a commercial product is not an option for me... Thanks anyway!

Comment: @andars:  Does your referenced parser convert ASTs back to source code?

Comment: @IraBaxter I tested out javaparser (suggested by @andars), and yes, it does print the AST back to source code.